# How to run a script when password is entered at the lock screen?

Tags: lubuntu, scripts, udev, wakeup

To toggle the enabling/disabling of my notebook's touchpad according to connected USB mouse, I used touchpad-indicator, which runs a daemon to monitor connected devices and take appropriate action.
When I send notebook to sleep and then unplug my mouse, on the wake up, the touchpad is disabled, so I have to connect-disconnect the mouse to enable it! I've searched this forum for the problem and both found solutions (adding script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` or `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d`) didn't work!
I've put up a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438179/how-can-i-toggle-the-touchpad-depending-on-whether-a-mouse-is-connected) to solve it, but after all, even when re-worked using udev's rules instead of touchpad-indicator, the problem still persists!

I want to clarify it: if touchpad was disabled on system level (i. e. disabled before even logging in, and the script would lie in `rc.local`, which, however, I tried, and it didn't work), putting scripts in /etc/pm and usr/lib/pm-utils *may work*.

But it is disabled on session level or whatever level does udev apply to. Can you please tell me where to put scripts which will run when I enter the password? **NOT LOG-IN, BUT ENTER PASSWORD** e.g. after wakeup.

Update: 
@terdon You didn't quite get it. I don't even have xscreensaver enabled, I doubt if it is even installed. You see, because my account has a password, if I press "Log out" or "Change user" OR SLEEP MODE, after that I will have to enter my password, and it has nothing to do with xscreensaver OR ANY SCREENSAVERS I DON'T HAVE THEM.

I tried what you suggested before asking this question and it didn't work out.

Update 2:
Ok, after some investigation I can tell that it's a Lubuntu specific problem. I am working now on "befriending" lightdm (which I guess applies on some level *other* than udev) and udev. Anybody with any experience with lighdm is appreciated.

Update 3:
Thanks to [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM#Autorun_a_Command_when_the_User_Session_starts) I (correctly?) figured out where to put the call of my script.
So I added `session-setup-script=/home/n76/tptoggle.sh` to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`
The current situation is the same as in the beginning, except that lightdm **is actually trying to put touchpad on when user session starts**

The problem isn't gone, but I feel that I'm close and it's just about giving lightdm the right privileges.

Please suggest how to do it.

Comment: I may have your answer, but I may have to ask you to clarify what you mean by "not log in, but enter password." Do you mean you need it to run prior to pressing "enter" on your password?

Comment: You have a scrrensaver , but is called `gnome-screensaver` and I'm sure that is running on your system. You can check using this command: `ps aux | grep gnome-screensaver`.

Comment: Will test tomorrow

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I don't have *any* screensavers

Comment: @Githlar run not prior but *after* pressing enter after password is entered

Comment: @Sneetsher yes, run the script. It's in the terdon's answer, I said that a couple of times. Anyways, is there any other (more priveleged) X server authorization file (similar to .Xauth in home folder) that can help udev run the script using same rights as LightDM does?

Comment: You could hook the script into PAM so the script executes after you've successfully entered your password (system login, not GUI log in -- though the GUI does utilize PAM), I believe this will make it run regardless of whether it's a GUI login or not. Another downside is that modifying the PAM files will make it so that you manually have to update the PAM configuration if it changes (i.e. adding a PAM modules -- most people never do this) as it can no longer be auto-managed. Is that acceptable?

Comment: @Githlar Anyways, I have 4 hours to award the bounty, go post this advice as answer (because I find this method acceptable), I'll give you the 100 rep. I just had no time to try it, so will try it later.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a way to run things after entering your password as you request and I doubt there will be since that is handled by the desktop environment (probably the screensaver daemon). However, it should work perfectly well if you add the right scripts to `/etc/pm/sleep.d`. Since you have not shown the scripts you've tried, my guess is that you simply did not write the script correctly. The following works fine on my system:

1. Create a file called `/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_resume` with the following contents:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   case "$1" in
       thaw|resume)
       /home/terdon/scripts/onoff.sh
       ;;
   esac
   exit $?
   ```

   Make sure to adapt the path above (`/home/terdon/scripts/onoff.sh`) to the actual path of the script shown in step 3.
2. Give the file the right permissions (`rwxr-xr-x`)

   ```
   sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_resume
   ```
3. Write a script that turns off the touchpad if a mouse is connected and on if there is no connected mouse:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   ## Get the xinput ID of the touchpad
   TID=$(xinput list | grep -iPo 'touchpad.*id=\K\d+')

   ## Check if a mouse is connected and act accordingly
   xinput list | grep -iq mouse &&  xinput disable "$TID" || xinput enable "$TID"
   ```

   Now save the script above using the path and name from step 1 (in this example, `/home/terdon/scripts/onoff.sh`), make it executable (`chmod +x /home/terdon/scripts/onoff.sh`) and you should be set.

If this is what you've already tried, please edit your question and show us the scripts you've used.

---

The other approach I can think of is to use the procedure outlined in my [answer to your other question](https://askubuntu.com/a/438220/85695). I don't understand what you have against loops, they are a perfectly valid and indeed invaluable programming construct. The only issue I can think of is that running an infinite loop can tax your CPU but that should not be a problem if your script uses `sleep` to wait for a second or two between each loop run. Since my suggestion does just that, you can simply use that if the above fails you.