# HP Spectre x360 disable trackpad in tablet mode

Tags: touchpad

I have the HP Spectre x360 and when I bend the laptop back into tablet mode (360 hinges), usually the keyboard and mouse disables in Windows.

In Ubuntu 15.04 the keyboard successfully disables, but not the trackpad.

What wizardry can I perform to rectify this issue?

Hopefully I could create an actively running script where it listens for particular events (activation of tablet mode) and then disable the track pad once boolean value equals True or something. I could probably get the ball rolling if there was a command out there that would display what component is being used / activated, so I could capture the event ID or something (not sure if this is even possible, just speculating...)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have such device neither have any system info. This is a generic answer.

1. Check for events

   - Get list of all input devices:

     ```
     xinput
     ```
   - Using regular mode
   - Run these on separate terminals

     ```
     udevadm monitor
     acpi_listen
     while sleep 1; do clear;for i in $(xinput --list --id-only); do echo $i $(xinput list-props $i | grep "Device Enabled"); done; done
     ```
   - Watch those commands output, while changing to tablet mode & back
2. Use that event to enable or disable track pad  xinput device, example

   ```
   xinput disable "AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint"
   xinput enable "AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint"
   ```

Quiet to board to go through all event types, but there are many question here in Ask Ubuntu for similar cases.

- UDEV: [How can I toggle the touchpad depending on whether a mouse is connected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438179/how-can-i-toggle-the-touchpad-depending-on-whether-a-mouse-is-connected)
- ACPI: [What code is executed when headphones are disconnected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640741/what-code-is-executed-when-headphones-are-disconnected/642404#642404)
- XINPUT: use a loop