# How to disable notebook's touchpad on USB mouse connect (and slower the last)?

Tags: 14.04, usb, mouse, touchpad

I do **not** have `function key` / <kbd>fn</kbd> for that :( .

Any ideas? Maybe there are settings or commands?

---

Other subjects were NOT helpful:

- `gpointing-device-settings` (auto-disable setting gets unticked);
- `kde-config-touchpad` (can not be installed alone);
- no idea how to use`udevd` .

Comment: Refer to the app metioned on this answer:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/58584/can-i-automatically-deactivate-my-touchpad-when-a-usb-mouse-is-connected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLUTION - not automatic**

The script below, when executed, will **disable the touchpad if any mouse is connected** and show a notification.

```
touchpad_id=$(xinput | grep -i "touchpad" | cut -f2 | cut -d '=' -f2);


if xinput | grep -i "mouse" | grep -i "pointer"

    then xinput set-prop $touchpad_id "Device Enabled" 0 |
         notify-send "Disabling the touchpad..." ""

    else xinput set-prop $touchpad_id "Device Enabled" 1 |
         notify-send "The touchpad is now enabled." ""

fi
```

Added there also a reverse situation, although in my case the touchpad gets enabled on mouse disconnection anyway.
I have saved the script in a file and am running it from `Unity Launcher` `Terminal` section after every mouse plug in.

---

**ADVANCED**

1. **More mouses?**

   Clarify which `mouse` should deactivate the touchpad by expanding the value in `"mouse"` fragment, name based on `xinput` devices list.
2. **Scared mouse runs from edge to edge?**

   I had to run additional command for mouse - decreasing `cursor acceleration` since it is madly set to 10 on every connection. Actually after a while I made auto-detection script (it gets mouse id and its' prop for velocity; dunno about performance of `cut`)...

   ```
   touchpad_id=$(xinput | grep -i "touchpad" | cut -f2 | cut -d '=' -f2);
   mouse_id=$(xinput | grep -i "mouse" | grep -i 'pointer' | cut -f2 | cut -d '=' -f2);
   mouse_prop=$(xinput list-props $mouse_id | grep -i "velocity" | cut -f2 | cut -d '(' -f2 | cut -d ')' -f1 );


   if xinput | grep -i "mouse" | grep -i "pointer"

       then xinput set-prop $touchpad_id "Device Enabled" 0 |
            xinput set-prop $mouse_id $mouse_prop 3 |
            notify-send "Disabling the touchpad..." ""

       else xinput set-prop $touchpad_id "Device Enabled" 1 |
            notify-send "The touchpad is now enabled." ""

   fi
   ```

Learned a lot today to make above :D .

---

**SOMEONE PRO?**

1. Would be useful to know how to make it automatic.
2. Also curious why mouse config is not saved (2.).

Answer (score 9):

**Solution - automatic**

Thanks to Esamo and his work.

To add AUTO triggers for connecting mouse on startup:

Create the file: `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules`

Fill up with this content: (replace $USER with your user name)

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="mouse[0-9]", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0",ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/$USER/.Xauthority", ENV{ID_CLASS}="mouse", RUN+="/home/$USER/scripts/touchpad_switcher.sh false"

ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="mouse[0-9]", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0",ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/$USER/.Xauthority", ENV{ID_CLASS}="mouse", RUN+="/home/$USER/scripts/touchpad_switcher.sh true"
```

**Example:**

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="mouse[0-9]", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0",ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/dawid/.Xauthority", ENV{ID_CLASS}="mouse", RUN+="/home/dawid/scripts/touchpad_switcher.sh false"

ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="mouse[0-9]", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0",ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/dawid/.Xauthority", ENV{ID_CLASS}="mouse", RUN+="/home/dawid/scripts/touchpad_switcher.sh true"
```

Next place your script wherever you want. I placed it in ~/scripts

**touchpad_switcher.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
enabled=$1
touchpad_id=$(xinput | grep -i "touchpad" | cut -f2 | cut -d '=' -f2);

if $enabled
then
  xinput set-prop $touchpad_id "Device Enabled" 1 | notify-send "The touchpad is now enabled." ""
else
  xinput set-prop $touchpad_id "Device Enabled" 0 | notify-send "Disabling the touchpad..." ""
fi
```

**Remember to add execute permissions:**

`chmod +x touchpad_switcher.sh`

Now simply reboot! ( merely restarting udev doesn't seem to work...)

---

Some other useful stuff:

Some info about [udev rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html)

[Example from ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Disable_trackpad_while_typing)

[Simlar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58584/can-i-automatically-deactivate-my-touchpad-when-a-usb-mouse-is-connected)

Comment: @Dawid Drozd Thanks for this answer for an important feature. Unfortunately it does not seem to fully work on my laptop  with Ubuntu 14.04. The notifications are shown (disabled, enabled) when the mouse is plugged in and out, but the touchpad continues to be enabled. Any tip?

Comment: @Filbuntu maybe can't find the right id? Try `xinput` and if your touchpad device doesn't have "touchpad" on it, that's the problem.

Comment: @lazel Thanks for the answer! `xinput`shows a touchpad: 
     `Virtual core pointer                     id=2 [master pointer  (3)]  
⎜   Virtual core XTEST pointer               id=4 [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   VGeneric USB K/B                          id=11 [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   V SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse                      id=12 [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   DLL0641:00 06CB:7621 UNKNOWN    id=14 [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   **SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad**               id=16 [slave  pointer  (2)]` - Any further tip?

Answer (score 1):

What @David Drozd posted didn't work for me on *Ubuntu 16.04*.

Seems like the trick with `xinput` don't work in `udev`. 
Only `synclient TouchpadOff=[0|1]` worked.
Also `ACTION="remove"` didn't work solely.

I finally got it when added `ENV{REMOVE_CMD}="/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/synclient TouchpadOff=0'"`

**The full solution**: create the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules`
with the following line (replace $USER with your user name)

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="mouse[0-9]", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0",ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/$USER/.Xauthority", ENV{REMOVE_CMD}="/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/synclient TouchpadOff=0'", RUN+="/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/synclient TouchpadOff=1' "
```