# Disable laptop touchpad after connecting mouse

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad

What are some ways to disable the laptop touchpad after connecting a mouse, which can either be wired (USB) or wireless (including Bluetooth)? I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/533266/how-to-disable-notebooks-touchpad-on-usb-mouse-connect-and-slower-the-last)